# Hbase Browser not loading

Tags: hbase

Hi I am using the cloudera quick start vm, and for one of the exercises I am following online, I have to use HBase but 
Hbase Browser is not loading

I followed the instructions and tried to install HBase Browser under the Hue panel,but it timedout with an error. I also tried restarting Hbase master server but it goes to stopped state immediately ,not sure why. I checked service status and it shows in stopped/failed state.

```
[cloudera@quickstart usr]$ sudo service hbase-master restart
```

no master to stop because kill -0 of pid 10105 failed with status 1

Stopped HBase master daemon: [ OK ]

starting master, logging to /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-master-quickstart.cloudera.out

Started HBase master daemon (hbase-master): [ OK ]

[cloudera@quickstart usr]$ service --status-all

...

HBase master daemon is dead and pid file exists [FAILED] -- Keeps showing as failed even after multiple restarts.

hbase-regionserver is running

HBase rest daemon is running [ OK ]

HBase Solr Indexer is not running [FAILED]

HBase thrift daemon is running [ OK ]

Hive Metastore is running [ OK ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufNg4.png)

I also checked the logs and this is the error message

2016-02-24 03:51:03,542 FATAL [quickstart:60000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Failed to become active master

java.io.IOException: error or interrupted while splitting logs in [hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase/WALs/quickstart.cloudera,60020,1455704843186-splitting] Task = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 1

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager.splitLogDistributed(SplitLogManager.java:289)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:390)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitMetaLog(MasterFileSystem.java:305)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitMetaLog(MasterFileSystem.java:296)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.splitMetaLogBeforeAssignment(HMaster.java:918)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:669)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:169)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1479)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-02-24 03:51:03,548 FATAL [quickstart:60000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Master server abort: loaded coprocessors are: []

2016-02-24 03:51:03,548 FATAL [quickstart:60000.activeMasterManager] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.

java.io.IOException: error or interrupted while splitting logs in [hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase/WALs/quickstart.cloudera,60020,1455704843186-splitting] Task = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 1

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager.splitLogDistributed(SplitLogManager.java:289)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:390)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitMetaLog(MasterFileSystem.java:305)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitMetaLog(MasterFileSystem.java:296)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.splitMetaLogBeforeAssignment(HMaster.java:918)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishActiveMasterInitialization(HMaster.java:669)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.access$500(HMaster.java:169)

at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster$1.run(HMaster.java:1479)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by recreating the cloudera quick VM and allocating more memory from 4GB to 6GB. HBase browser started without issues.